# How to dismiss Google Plus sign in 'Choose an Account' dialog programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, google-signin

Hi I have Google Plus Sign In in my app. I want to know how to dismiss 'Choose an Account' dialog programmatically.

When user clicks the sign in button, the sign in dialog shows. I have a problem when the dialog is shown, if I clear the RAM(using Clean Master app) and select the app from background the dialog shows again on top of the previous dialog.

So If I have a way to check if the sign in dialog is shown and dismissing it, I can easily dismiss it if the dialog is already shown before starting the Sign in intent.

How to do this? Please ask me if I need to provide my code. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Set a global boolean 'isSignInShown = true' whenever the sign in dialog pops up

Comment: Did you find any solution ?